# how do you set 2 table names in a model using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have created a model in Zend Framework 1.x which extends the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` class.

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php';

class Model_Account extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'accounts';

    public function someFunction()
    {
         //do something
    }

}
```

In Zend Framework, you have to declare the table name in the `$_name` property. At the moment, I only know how to declare one table name at a time, which means that my SQL statements will all be directed to the given table specified in the `$_name` property.

Is there a way to declare multiple tables in the model so that I can effectively execute a join statement?

Comment: This is Zend Framework 1.x..  Also, your question is unclear.

Comment: @mmmshuddup - thanks I've cleaned it up, hope this is more clear

Comment: This is still Zend Framework 1, _not_ 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm understanding that you want to have more than one model so you can execute a join.  Actually, you can accomplish a join *without* actually needing a second model.

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php';

class Model_Account extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'accounts';

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $otherTable = array('ot' => 'other_table');
        $columns    = array(
           'accounts.column_name', 
           'accounts.other_column_name'
        );
        $select = $this->select()
            ->from($this, $columns)
            ->join($otherTable, 'ot.accounts_id = accounts.id', array());

        $rowset = $this->fetchAll($select);
        return $rowset;
    }
}
```

If you want another model, just create a new PHP file in your *models* folder and declare your class there.

```
class Model_OtherTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'other_table';

    // ...
}
```

An example of using that would be:

```
$accounts = new Model_Account();
$results  = $accounts->someFunction();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->column_name, '<br>';
    echo $result->other_column_name, '<br>';
}

// to see output of result set do this
Zend_Debug::dump($results->toArray());
```

Comment: thank you... now how would I can I access the contents of each column? for example, would it be... 'echo $this->column_name' ?

Comment: Check edit.  If this answers your question then please accept.  Thank you. :)

Comment: thanks, my solution needed a bit of modifying but you got me on track.. much appreciated